# Significant Location changes not firing properly when device locked

Tags: ios, location, core-location

I am trying to figure out why `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` is not fired when using Significant Location Change when device is locked.

So far `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`gets fired with a new location **only after** waking up the device by pressing the home button.

I'm using iOS 8.1, but don't know if this is the normal behavior.

This is my code (AppDelegate.m):

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]){
            NSLog(@"LAUNCHED BY LOCATION UPDATE");
        }
        [self startLocationTrack];
    }

        -(void)startLocationTrack
    {
        if (_locationManager == nil) {
            _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            _locationManager.delegate = self;
            _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
            _locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
            _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
            if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
                [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }
            [_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        }else{
            [_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        }
    }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)location
    {    

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]];
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        [notification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
        notification.alertBody = @"YOU HAVE MOVE A SIGNIFICANT DISTANCE!!";
        notification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Read Msg", @"Read Msg");
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
        notification.repeatInterval=0;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you may not start tracking on application did launch, instead, somewhere else, when the app was already launched, you can check if your app has been authorized or not

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

And your delegate should wait for this

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
}
```

You need to add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your Info.plist file too or the user will never be prompted to authorize your app, once your app has been authorized you can start tracking the device

I have to mention that the locationManager is somewhere else and not as a property in the AppDelegate, I've used a static var, accesible with a singleton but you may have another way to access